# pandas.Series equivalent in spark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a script written in pandas and I need to port it into apche spark (pyspark). I have done all the other stuff but I can't seem to find a way to convert a pandas series into spark. For instance, what would be the equivalent of the following line in spark?

```
sr = pandas.Series(['', '', '', '', ''])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than asking about a direct conversion between "pandas series into spark" , it would be better to tell us what you want to do with this series object in Spark. You can actually keep it just as a list and do all your operations.

Comment: @GauravDhama you're probably right. I'll just keep it as a list. But just out of curiosity, is there a spark equivalent?

Comment: `sql.functions.Column()` or `sql.functions.col()` is a column, `sql.functions.Row()` is a row.